# Swift UI: UIHostingController.view is not fit to content view size at iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, uihostingcontroller

[image: iOS 13]
[image: iOS 14]

I want to update Swift UI View according to the communication result.
But UIHostingController.view is not fit rootView size at iOS 13.
The same thing happens when I try with the sample code below.
I want to add self-sizing SwiftUI View to UIStackView, but SwiftUI View overlaps with the previous and next views is occurring because this problem.
How can I avoid this problem?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let object = SampleObject()
        let sampleView = SampleView(object: object)
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: sampleView)
        hosting.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        addChild(hosting)
        view.addSubview(hosting.view)
        hosting.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hosting.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        hosting.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        hosting.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        hosting.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            object.test()
        }
    }
}


struct SampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var object: SampleObject
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("test1").background(Color.blue)
            Text("test2").background(Color.red)
            if object.state.isVisibleText {
                Text("test2").background(Color.gray)
            }
        }
        .padding(32)
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}


final class SampleObject: ObservableObject {
    struct ViewState {
        var isVisibleText: Bool = false
    }
    
    @Published private(set) var state = ViewState()
    
    func test() {
        state.isVisibleText = true
    }
}
```

If addSubview to UIStackView as below, the height of Swift UI View will not change in iOS13.
[image]

iOS13 (incorrect)
[image]

iOS14 (correct)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for iOS 13

Try this:

Every time the view size change, call this:

```
sampleView.view.removeFromSuperview()
let sampleView = SampleView(object: object)
let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: sampleView)
view.addArrangedSubview(hosting.view)
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention it, but I fixed it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You have not set the bottom anchor, add this line

```
hosting.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Another easy way is to set frame to hosting controller view and remove the constraint.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let object = SampleObject()
        let sampleView = SampleView(object: object)
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: sampleView)
        hosting.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds //<---here
        hosting.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        addChild(hosting)
        view.addSubview(hosting.view)
        hosting.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            object.test()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this workaround, the screen size and Swift UI View size will be the same. But I want the size of Swift UI View to be self-sizing.

Comment: can you add an image for what you want?

Comment: I want to make it look like the attached iOS 14 image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2SUq.jpg

Comment: I added description & ScreenShot. Please check it.

Comment: @RajaKishan is totally right - you have to add top + **bottom** + leading + trailing constraints.

Comment: if add top + bottom + leading + trailing constraints, SampleView's size is equal to ViewController.view's size. But I want SampleView to decide its own size. I don't want it to be displayed large in the center. I want to display in the minimum required size.

Comment: `UIViewController.view` doesn't have any default size/constraints, so if you add child view with **all** constraints then this child will decide the size of parent view (you can test this with UIKit views). However in your case I think there is a bug in iOS 13. UIStackView doesn't listen to SwiftUI views changes. I tried several approaches and nothing worked, but everything works fine on iOS 14.

Comment: Yes, I also think it's a bug in iOS 13.There is no direct solution to this problem, so I'm looking for a workaround.